# Was St. Patrick a really Roman Catholic and did he keep the 7th day Sabbath?

Tags: church-history

Does anyone have a  historical reference  that Saint Patrick actually kept the seventh day Sabbath and was not a Roman Catholic?

Comment: Why do you think he wasn't a Roman Catholic? Who is claiming that?

Comment: Is this the source of your question: [St. Patrick kept the Sabbath](http://12tribehistory.com/st-patrick-kept-the-sabbath/)?

Comment: @curiousdannii  The Church of Ireland Dean of Down says Patrick was neither Protestant nor Roman Catholic. Several Irish  politicians in the below link have said he was what today would be described as Protestant.  More generally, Celtic Christianity is often spoken of as in contrast to "Roman" Catholicism, and often not. Some say it was closer to Orthodox. .Is there even a definition of  Roman Catholic  in a 5th century  context?.   http://www.irishnews.com/news/2016/01/22/news/-protestant-st-patrick-row-sparks-religious-debate-390776/

Comment: @davidlol I wasn't necessarily implying that I disagree, just that the OP should be adding information like that into their question :)

Comment: @curiousdannii   Aha = Sorry, I failed to realise that.

Comment: There are traditions that say that the early Irish Church was founded by original Apostles in the first century, and practised a form of Christianity that was much more like that of the original Christians (e.g. Sabbath, Passover, kosher meat).  See page 349 of https://archive.org/details/celticscotlandhi02skenuoft/page/348 for "they did not duly reverence the Lord's day, but in this latter instance they seem to have followed a custom of which we find traces in the early Monastic Church of Ireland, by which they held Saturday to be the Sabbath on which they rested from all their labours" -1877

Answer (score 1):

The life of St. Patrick in a nutshell is that he was the son of well-to-do Roman citizens living in [Britannia](http://www.earlybritishkingdoms.com/maps/475_kingdoms.html), captured by Irish raiders, sold into slavery, eventually returned to home after finding his calling, was sent to Rome, became a bishop and was sent back to convert Ireland.  None of this well known history passed down through the ages corroborates that he was

1. Not a Latin Catholic (he was born in Britannia, which was a Roman Province )

> He had for his parents Calphurnius and Conchessa. The former belonged to a Roman family of high rank and held the office of decurio in Gaul or Britain.

2. Didn't give a hoot about Sunday. He certainly cared about Easter Sunday (which in good Catholic tradition considers the Sabbath to start on Saturday night) because that was the day he threw the gauntlet down with the Druids.

> On Easter Eve, in that year the feast of the Annunciation, and on the summit of the hill kindled the Paschal fire. The druids at once raised their voice. "O King", (they said) "live for ever; this fire, which has been lighted in defiance of the royal edict, will blaze for ever in this land unless it be this very night extinguished." By order of the king and the agency of the druids, repeated attempts were made to extinguish the blessed fire and to punish with death the intruder who had disobeyed the royal command. But the fire was not extinguished and Patrick shielded by the Divine power came unscathed from their snares and assaults. On Easter Day the missionary band having at their head the youth Benignus bearing aloft a copy of the Gospels, and followed by St. Patrick who with mitre and crozier was arrayed in full episcopal attire, proceeded in processional order to Tara.

You can read all about him in the [Old Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/11554a.htm) this [movie about](https://www.ignatius.com/St-Patrick-P2373.aspx) him was pretty good (about par for quality when it comes to saint movies).

Comment: Why do you  think he was an English boy?

Comment: Ok, not English, but definitely born on the island.  Have you read otherwise?

Comment: I have not read or heard otherwise than that he was born on the island of Great Britain. The Catholic Encyclopaedia article you link to says he was born in Scotland. I only discovered recently that New Mexico is part of  the US and I do not see why you would know more about the British Isles than I know about North America.  Please don't think I am being over=pedantic but over here the fact that Scotland is not part of England is kind of basic, and quite a big deal. . If you mean he was born on the island of Great Britain you might like to edit to say so..

Comment: @david OK good point, I don't think that affects his nationality much though.  I linked a 4th century map of Britain, I think it would be as much a mistake to call him Scottish as it would to call him English.

Comment: Yes I agree-- Scottish and English didn't have any meaning that far back. Besides although the most commonly accepted site is in modern Scotland there are other claims in modern  England and Wales.